# Find dynamic string in string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to find

```
f = "[[[someword_1234]]]"
```

inside

```
s = "weifjwieufh weifuwiefuhw ejfwi eujfh iwueh fiwe [[[someword_1234]]]"
```

but the literal `someword_1234` inside triple square brackets can change. So I cannot do:

```
s.find(f)
```

how can I approach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you need to match a *pattern* rather than static text, you should use the `re` module.  Specifically, you are looking for [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "weifjwieufh weifuwiefuhw ejfwi eujfh iwueh fiwe [[[someword_1234]]]"
>>> re.search(r'\[\[\[[^\]]+\]\]\]', s).group()
'[[[someword_1234]]]'
>>>
```

Below is an explanation of what the pattern matches:

```
\[\[\[  # [[[
[^\]]+  # One or more characters that are not ]
\]\]\]  # ]]]
```

Note that you need to escape `[` and `]` since they have special meaning in a Regex pattern.

Comment: Instead of `[^\]]+` you can use a non-greedy qualifier: `.+?`

Comment: @augurar - That works too.  However, it is generally slower because the parser needs to backtrack in order to match its pattern.  Using `[^\]]+` lets it get everything in one run.  You should always try to use negated character sets over non-greedy qualifiers to improve performance.